# Change jQuery Datetime Range Limit on Drupal 8

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, drupal

I need the jQuery countdown timer module on Drupal 8 to count down years from within the next 100 years.
How do I change the range limit for jquery? 
Where would I put the jquery code?

The maximum date I can use with the countdown timer is 2038 any higher then 2038 and the countdown will show 0's.
I've got this Jquery code:

```
yearRange: 'nn:+100'
```

But adding it to "jquery_countdown_timer.js" doesn't do anything?

I've also tried changing '#date_year_range' in 'jqueryCountdownTimerBlock.php' to

```
 '#date_year_range' => 'nn:+100'
```

which still does nothing.

Obviously the whole timer module will need to reconfigured to show the right countdown digits but I need the countdown timer to use dates above 2038 first.

Here's the files I'm working with 'JqueryCountdownTimerBlock.php':

```
<?php
/**
 * @file
 * Contains \Drupal\jquery_countdown_timer\Plugin\Block\JqueryCountdownTimerBlock.
 */

namespace Drupal\jquery_countdown_timer\Plugin\Block;

use Drupal\Core\Block\BlockBase;
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Datetime\DrupalDateTime;
use \DateTime;

/**
 * Provides a "Jquery Countdown Timer" block.
 *
 * @Block(
 *   id = "jquery_countdown_timer",
 *   admin_label = @Translation("Countdown Timer")
 * )
 */
class JqueryCountdownTimerBlock extends BlockBase {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function defaultConfiguration() {
    $font_size = 28;
    $dt = new DateTime('tomorrow');
    $countdown_datetime = $dt->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');

    return array('countdown_datetime' => $countdown_datetime, 'font_size' => $font_size);
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function blockForm($form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $form['jquery_countdown_timer_date'] = array(
      '#type' => 'datetime',
      '#title' => t('Timer date'),
      '#required' => 1,
      '#default_value' => new DrupalDateTime($this->configuration['countdown_datetime']),
      '#date_date_element' => 'date',
      '#date_time_element' => 'time',
      '#date_year_range' => '2016:+50',
    );
    $form['jquery_countdown_timer_font_size'] = array(
      '#type' => 'number',
      '#title' => t('Timer font size'),
      '#default_value' => $this->configuration['font_size'],
      '#required' => 1
    );

    return $form;
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function blockSubmit($form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $dt = $form_state->getValue('jquery_countdown_timer_date');
    $this->configuration['countdown_datetime'] = $dt->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    $this->configuration['font_size'] = $form_state->getValue('jquery_countdown_timer_font_size');
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function build() {

    $settings = array(
      'unixtimestamp' => strtotime($this->configuration['countdown_datetime']),
      'fontsize' => $this->configuration['font_size'],
    );

    $build = array();
    $build['content'] = array(
      '#markup' => '<div id="jquery-countdown-timer"></div><div id="jquery-countdown-timer-note"></div>',
    );

    // Attach library containing css and js files.
    $build['#attached']['library'][] = 'jquery_countdown_timer/countdown.timer';
    $build['#attached']['drupalSettings']['countdown'] = $settings;

    return $build;
  }
}
?>
```

jquery_countdown_timer_init.js:

```
(function ($, Drupal, drupalSettings) {
"use strict";
/**
 * Attaches the JS countdown behavior
 */
Drupal.behaviors.jsCountdownTimer = {
    attach: function (context) {
        var note = $('#jquery-countdown-timer-note'),
            ts = new Date(drupalSettings.countdown.unixtimestamp * 1000);

        $(context).find('#jquery-countdown-timer').once('jquery-countdown-timer').countdown({
            timestamp: ts,
            font_size: drupalSettings.countdown.fontsize,
            callback: function (weeks, days, hours, minutes, seconds) {
                var dateStrings = new Array();
                dateStrings['@weeks'] = Drupal.formatPlural(weeks, '1 week', '@count weeks');
                dateStrings['@days'] = Drupal.formatPlural(days, '1 day', '@count days');
                dateStrings['@hours'] = Drupal.formatPlural(hours, '1 hour', '@count hours');
                dateStrings['@minutes'] = Drupal.formatPlural(minutes, '1 minute', '@count minutes');
                dateStrings['@seconds'] = Drupal.formatPlural(seconds, '1 second', '@count seconds');
                var message = Drupal.t('@weeks, @days, @hours, @minutes, @seconds left', dateStrings);
                note.html(message);
            }
        });
    }
};})(jQuery, Drupal, drupalSettings);
```

jquery_countdown_timer.js:

```
    /**
 * @name        jQuery Countdown Plugin
 * @author      Martin Angelov
 * @version     1.0
 * @url         http://tutorialzine.com/2011/12/countdown-jquery/
 * @license     MIT License
 */

(function($){
    "use strict";

    // Creating the plugin
    $.fn.countdown = function(prop){

        var options = $.extend({
            callback : function(){},
            timestamp : 0,
            font_size : 0
        },prop);

        init(this, options);

        var positions = this.find('.position');

        (function tick(){

            // Time left
            var left = Math.floor((options.timestamp - (new Date())) / 1000);

            if(left < 0){
                left = 0;
            }

            var weeks = Math.floor(left/60/60/24/7),
                days = Math.floor(left/60/60/24) % 7,
                hours = Math.floor((left/(60*60)) % 24),
                minutes = Math.floor((left/60) % 60),
                seconds = left % 60;

            updateDuo(0, 1, weeks);
            updateDuo(2, 3, days);
            updateDuo(4, 5, hours);
            updateDuo(6, 7, minutes);
            updateDuo(8, 9, seconds);

            // Calling an optional user supplied callback
            options.callback(weeks, days, hours, minutes, seconds);

            // Scheduling another call of this function in 1s
            setTimeout(tick, 1000);
        })();

        // This function updates two digit positions at once
        function updateDuo(minor,major,value){
            switchDigit(positions.eq(minor),Math.floor(value/10)%10);
            switchDigit(positions.eq(major),value%10);
        }

        return this;
    };


    function init(elem, options){
        elem.addClass('countdownHolder').css({ 'font-size': options.font_size+'px' });

        // Creating the markup inside the container
        $.each(['Weeks','Days','Hrs','Mins','Secs'],function(i){
            $('<span class="count'+this+'">'+
                '<span class="position">'+
                '<span class="digit static">0</span>'+
                '</span>'+
                '<span class="position">'+
                '<span class="digit static">0</span>'+
                '</span>'
            ).appendTo(elem);

            if(this!="Secs"){
                elem.append('<span class="countDiv countDiv'+i+'"></span>');
            }
        });
    }

    // Creates an animated transition between the two numbers
    function switchDigit(position,number){

        var digit = position.find('.digit')

        if(digit.is(':animated')){
            return false;
        }

        if(position.data('digit') == number){
            // We are already showing this number
            return false;
        }

        position.data('digit', number);

        var replacement = $('<span>',{
            'class':'digit',
            css:{
                top:'-2.1em',
                opacity:0
            },
            html:number
        });

        // The .static class is added when the animation
        // completes. This makes it run smoother.

        digit
            .before(replacement)
            .removeClass('static')
            .animate({top:'2.5em',opacity:0},'fast',function(){
                digit.remove();
            });

        replacement
            .delay(100)
            .animate({top:0,opacity:1},'fast',function(){
                replacement.addClass('static');
            });
    }
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Still not sure what's causing the issue but since I only need 1 Date saved I found this work around. In jquery_countdown_timer_init.js change line
`ts = new Date(drupalSettings.countdown.unixtimestamp * 1000);` to the date you need like so
`ts = new Date("July 15, 2055 00:00:00");`